# Trouble sharing Slack file in channel using files.upload API in Python

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm working on a Python script to upload a file to a Slack channel using the files.upload API with the slack_sdk library. The script seems to be working fine as it returns a success response with the file ID, but the file is not visible in the specified channel.

```
import os
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError


slack_token = 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
channel_id = 'your_channel_id'
file_path = 'path/to/your/file.txt'

def upload_file_to_slack(token, channel, file_path):
    client = WebClient(token=token)

    try:
        response = client.files_upload(
            channels=channel,
            file=file_path
        )
        print("File uploaded successfully. File ID:", response['file']['id'])
    except SlackApiError as e:
        print("Error uploading file:", e.response['error'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    upload_file_to_slack(slack_token, channel_id, file_path)
```

Issue:

I'm receiving a successful response with the file ID.
However, the file is not appearing in the Slack channel.
I've checked the permissions and channel settings.

I would appreciate any insights into why the file is not being shared in the channel despite the successful response. Should I include the channel ID in a specific way, or is there something else I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a result of the bot not being on the channel as noted at https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/web/index.html#files_upload under the Files heading.
Are you sure the bot has been invited to the channel?
Secondly, you can try using files_uplaod_v2 as described here:
https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/releases/tag/v3.19.0

Comment: Hi, the bot is present in the channel. Also, i have tried using v2 api but no luck.

Comment: Please update your question to include  a print of your response object.

Comment: Hey, I found the issue. It seems for slack accounts with free subscriptions have certain limitations to upload files.